# maven plugin: inject default value with a properties file?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I write a maven plugin and want to keep default values centrally,
e.g. in a properties file

```
param1Name=param1Value
param2Name=42
```

Then in the settings i would like to refer to this.
Maybe

```
@Parameter(name="param1Name", defaultValue=${param1Value})
private name
```

but how is filtering done?
What I can do only is to specify the variable `${param1Value}` in the pom,
but I think this is not the right place.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to put the default value into the attribute `defaultValue=` because that has the advantage to get the default values rendered if you generate the plugin documentation site also if you request help on command line. I don't see any adavantage to have those values somewhere else than where really defined ...

Comment: @hkmanbaise: interesting what you say about help. But maybe I dont understand really. 
Do you speak about mvn latex:help in this case? (the name is latex-maven-plugin)? But this yields help only on goals. Is there a way to get the config and the default values??? 

Also your hint at the documentation site is not so clear to me... maybe there is some information missing in my brain. I wanted to write site documentation by hand, along the lines of say compiler plugin. 
is there a more automatic way?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about `mvn latex:help` and you can do that and try for example: `mvn compiler:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=compile`... which is supported for any plugin also for `mvn latex:help`(read that output)... for the plugins just use this as example: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html (This site is generated suring the site generation!)...

Comment: @khmarbaise.. ahh. I also tried mvn latex:help -Ddetail=true... better with a goal in addition as you did. 
The problem here is: I package my config in classes, so details are not visible... 
Seemingly, parameters are expected to form a flat hierarchy.. well, no hierarchy. ... 

Can you confirm this?

Comment: @khmarbaise: you want to say that the documentation of the clean plugin is generated? 
Hm... but how to do it? 
I want to try also.

Comment: I say it is generated... not 100% of course (https://github.com/apache/maven-clean-plugin/) The "goal" part is generated which uses things like `@Parameter` etc. see in the `site` directory ... https://github.com/apache/maven-clean-plugin/tree/master/src/site and also check https://github.com/apache/maven-clean-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/clean/CleanMojo.java related to the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html parts...

Comment: And that part for the goal(s) is very important for everybody who want to use that plugin... you can see which goals exists, what parameters exists and what the default values are... etc... a very convenient way...

Comment: I will try as soon as possible.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I have problems using help plugin properly because I have nested config. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76815594/maven-plugins-access-to-nested-configuration-in-help-plugin In general, a good idea, spares a lot of work on documentation.