# maven plugins access to nested configuration in help plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I write a plugin with a lot of configurable parameters: latex-maven-plugin.
I cite from the mojo
https://github.com/Reissner/latex-maven-plugin/blob/master/maven-latex-plugin/src/main/java/eu/simuline/m2latex/mojo/AbstractLatexMojo.java:

```
  /**
   * ...
   */
  @Parameter(name = "versionsWarnOnly", defaultValue = "false")
  private boolean versionsWarnOnly;

  /**
   * ...
   */
  // for help plugin this does not fit. 
  // also not ideal that settings is all the same independent of target. 
  // also for help plugin this is not detailed enough. 
  @Parameter(name = "settings")
  protected Settings settings;
```

The parameter `settings` contains parameters itself.
Since there is really a lot of parameters, I would even like to restructure this
and use more of these parameter classes like `Settings`.

The only problem with this technique is, that the `help` plugin displays two parameters only
and ignores the parameters nested in `settings`.

How can I make `mvn latex:help -Ddetail=true` display the leaf parameters instead of bare parameter `settings`?

Comment: The first question is why do you need a lot of parameters... think from the user point of view... only parameters which are really needed... not more.. as many as possible defaults...

Comment: Well, practically i can stick to the default in most time. 
But nevertheless, it offers a lot of flexibility to have parameters. 
In this special case, the plugin orchestrates a lot of auxiliary programs. 
So I made configurable the name, the parameter to invoke. 
Most write log files and the errors and warnings extracted are reverse engineered. 
So it is save to define both as parameters. 

You can see, this amounts to 4 parameter per tool. 
For each graphical converter there is a separate tool, well almost for each. 
... and so on.

Comment: @hkmarbaise, well I can understand that many parameters may look like bad design. 
The question is on something different: 
Plugins allow to strcuture config in objects as fields. 
In itself this is nice because it is a technique to structure the set of parameters. 

The problem for me is, that this does not fit the help plugin, which does not take these nested parameters into account.

Comment: Try to check https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java (this has also separted parameters etc.)..

Comment: Do you think specifically of the parameter archive? 
But this also occurs as a single parameter in the help text. 
`archive
      The archive configuration to use. See Maven Archiver Reference.`
The author inserts a link after the 'see' but the help plugin does nothing but inserting the replacement text of course. 

If you think of this, it is also not satisfactory. In fact, the jar plugin has the same problems as mine in this respect.